# Set form to dirty state (AngularJS) after change in datetimepicker (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm have a [Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)  input filed on my webpage and I'm trying to enable 'Edit' button whenever change is made to existing data. The problem is that change of datetime using datatimepicker is not marking my form as 'dirty', so button is greyed out permanently.

```
<input type="submit"  value="{{!myCtrl.thing.id ? 'Add' : 'Update'}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || myForm.$pristine">
```

I know how to catch datatime change event using JQuery, but I don't have any idea how to access 'myForm' to change it's state to dirty.

```
<form ng-submit="myCtrl.submit()" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="date">Date:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="input-group date" id='datetimepicker'>
                <input class="form-control" name="date" id="datetimepicker1" placeholder="select date">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                });
            });
            $("#datetimepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {
                //CODE TO set myForm to 'dirty' state.
            });
        </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set it using the general form `[formName].$setDirty()`. So for you it would be: `myForm.$setDirty()`.

Comment: In that solution I've got `Uncaught TypeError: myForm.$setDirty is not a function`

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're using jQuery. I would recommend using the [UI Bootstrap directives specifically designed for Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup) and avoid using jQuery with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to set a directive to handle jQuery stuff?

```
mainModule.directive('datePickerHandler', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $(el).datetimepicker({}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
                scope.myForm.$setDirty();
            });
        });
    }
}
});
```

Then you can have access to the scope directives like form.